# Index was outside the bounds of the array while exporting data to excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus-4

I have `ASP.Net` site. Following is my method to write stream to excel.

```
public void JsonToExcel(string jsonData, HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        try
        {
            ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
            var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            //below line is throwing the error
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(jsonData, true);
            using (MemoryStream swObj = new MemoryStream())
            {
                string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + ".xlsx";
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName + "");
                excel.SaveAs(swObj);
                swObj.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }
```

At this line of the function 
-`worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(jsonData, true);`

I am getting the following exception

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

I tried setting to `worksheet.Cells[0,0]`

I am using **EPPlus 4.1.0** package.

JSON Sample :-

```
        string jsonData = @"jsonData = [
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:06:25.083"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    },
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:12:02.497"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    },
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:13:48.013"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    }]";
```

Comment: one of the problems with working with excel is that the cells are not zero based indexes,  youre better off using Closed XML found here https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you please post a sample JSON data and the expected Excel conversion?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh. I have posted the sample JSON

Comment: Could you please add the full callstack of the exception? It's not clear where exactly the error occurs

Comment: @SimonPrice you misunderstand cell indexes  *and* what ClosedXml does - which is *exactly* the same thing as EPPlus. Both use indexes, both use addresses. You just pick one access method. In the end, both work with Excel sheets so they can't use arbitrary access methods

Comment: @Kgn-web `LoadFromCollection` works with *collections*, not arbitrary strings. Did you forget to deserialize the string perhaps? Should the question be closed as a typo?

Comment: @SimonPrice no, I just know Excel and I *did* offer a solution. Deserialize the string into a collection first. Vladislav offered a complete answer. There is nothing wrong with `Cells[1,1]`. No reason to switch to ClosedXML, or use the address syntax (A1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think that it's problem with JSON and EPPlus method LoadFromCollection internals</s> LoadFromCollection method expects a collection, not an arbitrary string or something else, so when I deserialized it to a appropriate class with Newtonsoft.Json it seems to be OK.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace TestC
{
    public class PostData
    {
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActionDate { get; set; }
        public string ActionType { get; set; }
        public string ActionPerformedBy { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage()) {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                string jsonData = @"[
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:06:25.083"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    },
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:12:02.497"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    },
                    {
                        ""DocumentName"": ""Test Document"",
                        ""ActionDate"": ""2015-09-25T16:13:48.013"",
                        ""ActionType"": ""View"",
                        ""ActionPerformedBy"": ""Sreeja SJ""
                    }]";

                List<PostData> dataForExcel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PostData>>(jsonData);

                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(dataForExcel, true);

                package.SaveAs(File.Create(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\sample.xlsx"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

[image: Excel]

---

For correct date output in Excel you should apply correct number format for cells in second column (ActionDate) starting from second row to the end:

```
worksheet.Cells[2, 2, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000";
```

Comment: This isn't a matter of internals. `LoadFromCollection` expects a *collection*. It doesn't parse Json, XML or other arbitrary formats.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep, understand now

Comment: @VladislavKhapin Exactly! It expects an IEnumerable collection as the input parameter.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, If am doing so, the `ActionDate` is getting value in the format as **42272.67503** in the downloaded excel

Comment: @Kgn-web That *is* how dates are stored in Excel. They are displayed as dates only because Excel applies a date format over the value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in chrome I am getting an exception `Error code: ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION`

Comment: @VladislavKhapin. Great really appreciate your efforts!! Thanks

Comment: @VladislavKhapin. just 1 more thing to ask. Whats **T** in the  `2015-09-25T16:06:25.083`

Comment: @Kgn-web its a [delimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like <date>T<time>